# How does the axiom schema of replacement work?

Tags: logic, set-theory, propositional-calculus

According to [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Axiom:Axiom_of_Replacement)
website, the first partion of this axiom schema is

> Let $P(y,z)$ be a propositional function, which determines a function.
>
> That is, we have $∀y(∃x:(∀z:(P(y,z)⟺(x=z))))$.

How does the second sentence mean that "$P(y,z)$ determines a function"? I can't even understand what does it mean for a propositional function "to define a function" in English, let alone understand how this relates to the WFF shown here.

Can anyone try explaining this thing to me?

Comment: "for all humans ($y$) there is a man ($x$) such that, for all humans ($z$), if $z$ is **father of** $y$, then $x=z$"; in other words, $P(y,x)$ reads: "$x$ is **father of** $y$" and it is a *function*: no humans has more than one father.

Answer (score 2):

The formula in the second sentence says that for each $y$, there exists a unique $x$ such that $P(y,x)$ is true.  This means that you can define a function $f$ by saying that $f(y)$ is the unique $x$ such that $P(y,x)$ is true.  This function is essentially equivalent to the formula $P$, since given this function, $P(y,x)$ is equivalent to "$f(y)=x$".

Answer (score 2):

Remember that a function $f$ from $Y$ to $Z$ takes in an element of $Y$, and spits out an element of $Z$. That is:

> For each $y\in Y$, there is a unique $z\in Z$ such that $f(y)=z$.

The WFF you point to is saying that the predicate $P(y, z)$ behaves in the same way: for each $y$, there is a unique $z$ such that $P(y, z)$ holds.