# How does the second part of the axiom schema of replacement imply that the image of the function created in the first part is a set?

Tags: set-theory

Thanks to the post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1823840/how-does-the-axiom-schema-of-replacement-work), I understand how the first part of that axiom schema, ${\forall}y({\exists}x:({\forall}z(P(y,z){\iff}(x=z))))$, defines a function.

The idea replacement conveys is that the image of every such function is a set. It can be supposedly expressed as a WFF as $∀w(∃x:(∀y((y∈w)⟹(∀z(P(y,z)⟹(z∈x))))))$.

I don't see how this works either. I'd want an explanation, preferably with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image of $P(y, z)$, where the input is $y$ and the output is $z$, does not necessarily output a set. It outputs the element $z$, which is the element which will replace $y$.

Our original set is $w$. What this statement says is that we can take $w$ and find a set $x$ such that for any $y \in w$, we have the corresponding element $z \in x$, where $P(y, z)$. This means that we use $P(y, z)$ to look at the elements of $w$ and then output a new element to put in $x$. $y$ is the old element that is in the old set $w$ and $z$ is the new element that is in the new set $x$.

---

For example, let's say we have $w=\{1,2,3\}$ and $P(y,z)$ is true iff $y-z=1$. Clearly, given $y$, there is a unique solution to $y-z=1$. Now, by the Axiom Schema of Replacement, we can create a new set $x$ that takes every element in $w$ and has the corresponding $z$ element:
$$1 \in w \implies 0 \in x \text{ because } P(1, 0)$$
$$2 \in w \implies 1 \in x \text{ because } P(2, 1)$$
$$3 \in w \implies 2 \in x \text{ because } P(3, 2)$$

Comment: How can the output be $z$? Don't propositional functions give only "truth" and "false" outputs?

Comment: @cxzcxzcas Yes, the real output of $P(y, z)$ is "true" or "false". However, by the first part, for every $y$, there is only one corresponding $z$ such that $P(y, z)$. From this, we can create a function $f$ such that $f(y)=z$ if and only if $P(y, z)$. Therefore, $P(y, z)$ can be thought of as a function in that it determines how this function $f$ works.